# Are all nodes 'mining' nodes in a PoA network?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority

I now have my PoA network running and I can add nodes which are approved by the others. But I have a question about can we add read only nodes?

I do not really understand the different types of nodes in PoA but can we add a node which does not need any proposing process under clique.propose?

Answer (score 2):

There are no mining nodes on Clique chains - sealer nodes take it in turn to add new blocks to the chain and no mining is required.

You can add non-sealer nodes too; any nodes that join the network which aren't sealers (as in they aren't listed as a sealer in the genesis block and haven't been voted into sealer status with `clique.propose` since then) can sign and broadcast new transactions to their peers and query the current state but can't create any new blocks.

Comment: Thanks. But the logs all state "mining" I am not on my other PC now so I cannot copy paste, but the logs definitely stating mining.

Comment: Geth is written with PoW in mind - unfortunately it hasn't been updated so the terminology doesn't change for Clique implementations which is slightly misleading!